# What did DeepMind do with AlphaGo between the Fan Hui and Lee Sedol games?

Tags: deep-learning, reinforcement-learning

In January, DeepMind published the [article](http://www.nature.com/doifinder/10.1038/nature16961) (see [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SUbqykXVx0A)) about its win against Fan Hui, which happend in October 2015. The article and other interviews say, it used 100.000 human games, and then 13.000.000 self-plays. In January, many commentators where sceptical whether AlphaGo can win against Lee Sedol.

In March 2016 (5-6 months after Fan Hui's defeat), AlphaGo won against Lee Sedol.

I was searching through many documents, watched all games, read the papers, but could not find the answer to the question: *What did DeepMind do in the 5-6 months between the two games to improve the quality of AlphaGo to that level?*

Was it only further self-play? If so, are there some numbers of games that were played? Were there algorithmic advances?

I would love to understand that. Thank you!

Comment: I found [slides by David Silver](http://www0.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/d.silver/web/Resources_files/AlphaGo_IJCAI.pdf) who explained that the improved the policy network, the value network, the search; and the hardware by switching from GPU to TPU (tensor processor units).

Comment: And there is a [talk by Fan Hui and Aja Huang](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LX8Knl0g0LE) about the progress.